# Why StackingRegressor doesn't catch the trend?

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, data-mining, ensemble-learning, stacking

I just reviewed very good example of fitting `StackingRegressor` from **mlxtend** package.

```
from mlxtend.regressor import StackingRegressor 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge 
from sklearn.svm import SVR 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

# Generating a sample dataset 
np.random.seed(1) 
X = np.sort(5 * np.random.rand(40, 1), axis=0) 
y = np.sin(X).ravel()
y[::5] += 3 * (0.5 - np.random.rand(8))

# Initializing models

lr = LinearRegression() 
svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear') 
ridge = Ridge(random_state=1) 
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf')

stregr = StackingRegressor(regressors=[svr_lin, lr, ridge], 
                           meta_regressor=svr_rbf)

# Training the stacking regressor

stregr.fit(X, y) 
stregr.predict(X)

# Evaluate and visualize the fit

print("Mean Squared Error: %.4f"
      % np.mean((stregr.predict(X) - y) ** 2)) 
print('Variance Score: %.4f' % stregr.score(X, y))

with plt.style.context(('seaborn-whitegrid')):
    plt.scatter(X, y, c='lightgray')
    plt.plot(X, stregr.predict(X), c='darkgreen', lw=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

But, when I changed one line of generating the dataset, like:

```
y = np.sin(X).ravel() * np.cos(X).ravel()
```

I got totally bad fit of the StackerRegressor.
[image]

Please don't block that question and help me to understand. Thank you!